# Customize an MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

Warm greetings,

I'm using the below code to show an annotation on an iOS [mkmapview](/questions/tagged/mkmapview) when tapping on the map.

```
MKPointAnnotation *aAnnotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

aAnnotationPoint.title = @"Virginia";
aAnnotationPoint.subtitle = @"This is a test code .this is a test code. This is a test codeThis is a test code .this is a test code. This is a test code";

// Add the annotationPoint to the map
[myMapView addAnnotation:aAnnotationPoint];
```

The problem is that the annotation is not displaying the text fully - it cuts it off with `...`. This is the result:

[image]

I have searched for this kind of sample over the internet but no with no luck. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the size of `callout` through `MKPointAnnotation` is the same as you had shown in the image. Due to a very long subtitle the subtitle text is not displaying fully.

A solution to this problem is to go for the **[custom callouts from here](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/)**. Also try to take help from this **[wonderful tutorial](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/)** where the UIBarButton and UIImageView is given to pinView.

Hope you got my point. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply..using the below link you have provided http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/ where i need to change to display multi line text? jus to ensure this works for my scenerio...